# CMake include directory aliasing

Tags: c++, cmake

I've installed [mongocxx](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver) driver on Ubuntu, but there is a problem with including header files.

```
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>  // Error
#include <mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx/client.hpp>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>  // Error
#include <bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
```

Every header file of the driver calls another header files like `#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>` but compiler doesn't recognize it if I don't add parent directories.

(like `#include <mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx/client.hpp>`)

I think `mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx` should be aliased to `mongocxx`. Is there any way to do this in `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: I think you just have to `include_directories(mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx)` instead of `include_directories(mongocxx/)`.

Comment: @arrowd I added `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include/mongocxx/)` but still it has problems.

Comment: "I think `mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx` should be aliased to `mongocxx`. Is there any way to do this in `CMakeLists.txt` file?" - A compiler doesn't support include directories' *aliasing*. As CMake simply calls a compiler, it cannot provide such aliasing too.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the examples in the project for information on how to use `pkgconfig` or `find_package` to do this the correct way: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/projects/mongocxx/cmake/shared/CMakeLists.txt#L39